# Is it possible to http2 push assets among different domains?

Tags: php, nginx, push, http2

I have main site(site.com) and site where my resources(css,images,js) are located(somecdn.com). I want before login push some of this resources. I send ajax request and in response header set Link-s with resources. But my resources downloading with waiting and without any pushing(see attached picture). How can I enable http2 push for resources in somecdn.com?
[with push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePOVA.png)
[without push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9yOJ.png)

I create in docker two sites: site.com and somecdn.com and check that http2 push works correctly on both of them (and separately it works as supposed).

https://127.0.0.1:8081/index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>IndexPHP</h1></iframe>-->
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://127.0.0.1:8083/push.php', true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://127.0.0.1:8083/push.php

```
<?php

header("Link: </style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
header("Link: </image.png>; rel=preload; as=image", false);
```

I expect to see in Chrome dev-tools resources without waiting and with "Push" indication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to push resources for another domain. From the [HTTP/2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.2):

> The server MUST include a value in the ":authority" pseudo-header
> field for which the server is authoritative (see Section 10.1).  A
> client MUST treat a PUSH_PROMISE for which the server is not
> authoritative as a stream error (Section 5.4.2) of type
> PROTOCOL_ERROR.

You can preload the requests with those headers which will give the browser the hint to fetch them with a high priority even before it sees the actual requests for the resources later.

In fact many people recommend preload over push anyway, as [push is very complex](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/), not cache aware so too easy to abuse by over-pushing so causing a performance penalty, and so the benefits of it are questionable. That is why [usage of HTTP/2 push remains so low](http://dl.ifip.org/db/conf/networking/networking2017/1570332989.pdf).

Use of a sharded domain like this is generally discouraged under HTTP/2 as it loses many of the benefits of HTTP/2 which aims to move to a single connection for performance reasons. See this blog post for a good explanation on this: https://csswizardry.com/2019/05/self-host-your-static-assets/

Comment: Thank you! But what about workarounds? For example adding iframe from cdn seems can fix problem.

Comment: The workaround is to use preload, instead of push. Or alternatively self-host. I don't understand how adding an iframe from CDN would fix this - can you explain more what you mean about this?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Just check it. Yes, push is working, but when page need this resource situation repeat

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Is this resolved now? If so please accept the answer.

Comment: I accept your answer, thanks! Can't up vote it because of lack of reputation :(